Anchor program test with error: Transaction failed to sanitize accounts offsets correctly
hope someone can help me.
i modity the project which called AMM https://github.com/ironaddicteddog/anchor-amm
after update the version of anchor and rewrite test code.
but face the problem : Error: failed to send transaction: invalid transaction: Transaction failed to sanitize accounts offsets correctly
What error occurred in the code? How do I debug it?
here the code
program:
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    /// CHECK: Safe
    pub authority: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(signer, zero)]
    pub amm: Box<Account<'info, Amm>>,
    #[account(owner = amm.key(),mut)]
    pub pool_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(owner = amm.key(),mut)]
    pub token_a: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(owner = amm.key(),mut)]
    pub token_b: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub fee_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub destination: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
}

the test:
    const sig = await program.provider.connection.requestAirdrop(
      payer.publicKey,
      10000000000
    );
    await program.provider.connection.confirmTransaction(sig);

    [authority, bumpSeed] = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([ammAccount.publicKey.toBuffer()], program.programId);

    // creating pool mint
    poolMint = await createMint(
      programProvider.connection,
      payer,
      authority,
      null,
      2,
    );

    let feeAccount = await createAccount(
      programProvider.connection,
      payer,
      poolMint,
      owner.publicKey,
    );

    const tokenAccountPool = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      programProvider.connection,
      payer,
      poolMint,
      authority,
      true
    );


    let mintA = await createMint(
      programProvider.connection,
      payer,
      owner.publicKey,
      null,
      2,
    );

    const tokenAccountA = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      programProvider.connection,
      payer,
      mintA,
      authority,
      true
    );

    await mintTo(
      programProvider.connection,
      payer,
      mintA,
      tokenAccountA.address,
      owner,
      currentSwapTokenA
    );

    let mintB = await createMint(
      programProvider.connection,
      payer,
      owner.publicKey,
      null,
      2,
    );

    const tokenAccountB = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      programProvider.connection,
      payer,
      mintB,
      authority,
      true
    );

    await mintTo(
      programProvider.connection,
      payer,
      mintB,
      tokenAccountB.address,
      owner,
      2
    );

    const commandDataLayout = BufferLayout.struct([
      BufferLayout.nu64("tradeFeeNumerator"),
      BufferLayout.nu64("tradeFeeDenominator"),
      BufferLayout.nu64("ownerTradeFeeNumerator"),
      BufferLayout.nu64("ownerTradeFeeDenominator"),
      BufferLayout.nu64("ownerWithdrawFeeNumerator"),
      BufferLayout.nu64("ownerWithdrawFeeDenominator"),
      BufferLayout.nu64("hostFeeNumerator"),
      BufferLayout.nu64("hostFeeDenominator"),
      BufferLayout.u8("curveType"),
      BufferLayout.nu64("curveParameters"),
      // BufferLayout.blob(32, 'curveParameters'),
    ]);
    let data = Buffer.alloc(1024);
    const encodeLength = commandDataLayout.encode(
      {
        tradeFeeNumerator: TRADING_FEE_NUMERATOR,
        tradeFeeDenominator: TRADING_FEE_DENOMINATOR,
        ownerTradeFeeNumerator: OWNER_TRADING_FEE_NUMERATOR,
        ownerTradeFeeDenominator: OWNER_TRADING_FEE_DENOMINATOR,
        ownerWithdrawFeeNumerator: OWNER_WITHDRAW_FEE_NUMERATOR,
        ownerWithdrawFeeDenominator: OWNER_WITHDRAW_FEE_DENOMINATOR,
        hostFeeNumerator: HOST_FEE_NUMERATOR,
        hostFeeDenominator: HOST_FEE_DENOMINATOR,
        curveType: CurveType.ConstantProduct,
        curveParameters: 0,
      },
      data
    );
    data = data.slice(0, encodeLength);
    console.log("data encodeLength", encodeLength);

    const fees_input: TypeDef<
      {
        name: "FeesInput";
        type: {
          kind: "struct";
          fields: [
            {
              name: "tradeFeeNumerator";
              type: "u64";
            },
            {
              name: "tradeFeeDenominator";
              type: "u64";
            },
            {
              name: "ownerTradeFeeNumerator";
              type: "u64";
            },
            {
              name: "ownerTradeFeeDenominator";
              type: "u64";
            },
            {
              name: "ownerWithdrawFeeNumerator";
              type: "u64";
            },
            {
              name: "ownerWithdrawFeeDenominator";
              type: "u64";
            },
            {
              name: "hostFeeNumerator";
              type: "u64";
            },
            {
              name: "hostFeeDenominator";
              type: "u64";
            }
          ];
        };
      },
      Record<string, number>
    > = {
      tradeFeeNumerator: new anchor.BN(TRADING_FEE_NUMERATOR),
      tradeFeeDenominator: new anchor.BN(TRADING_FEE_DENOMINATOR),
      ownerTradeFeeNumerator: new anchor.BN(OWNER_TRADING_FEE_NUMERATOR),
      ownerTradeFeeDenominator: new anchor.BN(OWNER_TRADING_FEE_DENOMINATOR),
      ownerWithdrawFeeNumerator: new anchor.BN(OWNER_WITHDRAW_FEE_NUMERATOR),
      ownerWithdrawFeeDenominator: new anchor.BN(
        OWNER_WITHDRAW_FEE_DENOMINATOR
      ),
      hostFeeNumerator: new anchor.BN(HOST_FEE_NUMERATOR),
      hostFeeDenominator: new anchor.BN(HOST_FEE_DENOMINATOR),
    };
    const curve_input: TypeDef<
      {
        name: "CurveInput";
        type: {
          kind: "struct";
          fields: [
            {
              name: "curveType";
              type: "u8";
            },
            {
              name: "curveParameters";
              type: "u64";
            }
          ];
        };
      },
      Record<string, number>
    > = {
      curveType: CurveType.ConstantProduct,
      curveParameters: new anchor.BN(0),
    };

    await program.methods
      .initialize(fees_input, curve_input)
      .accounts({
        authority: authority,
        amm: ammAccount.publicKey,
        poolMint: poolMint,
        tokenA: tokenAccountA.address,
        tokenB: tokenAccountB.address,
        feeAccount: feeAccount,
        destination: tokenAccountPool.address,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      })
      .preInstructions([await program.account.amm.createInstruction(ammAccount, encodeLength)])
      .signers([ammAccount])
      .rpc();

